# ggplot2 - geom_histogram's binwidth with scale_x_log10

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to build an histogram with ggplot.
I don't quite grasp how binwidth works.

```
 library(ggplot2)
 set.seed(10)
 testData = data.frame(x=rlnorm(100, log(1), log(2.5)))
 ggplot(data=testData, aes(x=testData$x)) +
 geom_histogram(binwidth=1)+scale_x_log10()
```

How do I get 1 bar per order of magnitude ? 
(ie. 1 bar between 10^-1 and 10^0, 1 bar between 10^0 and 10^1, ...)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is using `cut()` function to group the data and then count by the group

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(10)
x=rlnorm(100, log(1), log(2.5))
testData = data.frame(x = x, grp = cut(x, c(0.1, 1, 10)))
ggplot(data=testData, aes(grp)) +
    stat_count()
```

Comment: Not quite the solution I was expecting but a great work around !
Say that, above this plot, I want to overlay a geom_density layer of the original dataset. Any advise on how to do that with your 'conversion-to-factor-solution' ? Thanks in advance.